# histogram nested loop not printing full graph

Tags: c, command-prompt

I have been going through [The C programming language (2nd addition)](https://www.amazon.ca/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628) exercises to try and improve my coding skills. I am currently on exercises 1-13 which requires you to write a program that prints a histogram of the lengths of words in its input.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INWORD 1
#define OUTOFWORD 0

main ()
{
int word_state;
int word_count, word_length, c;
int A_word_array[50];

word_count = word_length = c = 0;
word_state = OUTOFWORD;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    A_word_array[i] = 0;


    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == ' ') 
        {
            if (word_state == INWORD)
            {
            word_state = OUTOFWORD;
            word_length = 0;
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            if (word_state == OUTOFWORD)
            {
               ++word_length;
               ++word_count;
             A_word_array[word_count-1] = word_length;
             word_state = INWORD;
          
        
            }
        
            else
            {
              ++word_length;
                  A_word_array[word_count-1] = word_length;
          
            }
        }


    }

    for (int k = 0; k < word_count; k++)
    {

        for (int m = 0; m < A_word_array[k] ; m++)
        {
            printf("o");
        }

    printf("\n");
    
    }

}
```

For some reason when I run this code in command prompt for VS it begins to print the histogram but then abruptly stops. For example, if I were to write "This is a test code!" press enter and CTRL+ C (to end file) I get:

ooo^C

Instead of:

oooo

oo

o

oooo

ooooo
^C

This issue seems to stem fro the second for loop. I am unsure if it is a small error or just some limitation I am not aware of with command prompt V22 but I am stumped. Any and all guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dear ctrl+c is an escape sequence, it is interfering with your prompt, please try with another character to control the loop, I used the following:

`while ((c = getchar()) != '\n)`

it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Is there a reason why ctrl+c causes interference as opposed to other escape sequences?